# how to populate data in a hidden field based on the value of drop down list box in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

This is my code for a form that I have written for my app.

```
  <h3>Create Make Payment </h3>
  <td>  <%= simple_form_for(@payment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, collection:@arr,:required=>true,:id=>"email" ,:class=>"chosen-select"%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id,:value=>User.find_by_email(ar).id,:id=>"user_id" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :amount,:required=>true%>
  </div>

    <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :desc, as: :text ,:required=>true%>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In this the value for the user_id field should be dependent on what is chosen in the first field, i.e :email field. Which will have a collection of values from @arr array. How do I pass the value that is chosen in the email drop down list to the following code as var so that it returns a value which will be used as value for the hidden field user_id

```
User.find_by_email(ar).id
```

How do I do this? Should I user ajax? If so how?

Comment: If you have a select with an options array like [email_address, user_id], doesn't that mean that you are done? User selects an email address from dropdown, corresponding user_id is submitted with form. No need to send the email address to look up the user_id.

Comment: you can populate it on the controller b4 it saves.